# Only able to plot the last JSON array place in google maps in android

Tags: android, arrays, json, web-services, google-maps

I m trying to create an android application, where I am fetching a JSON array from web service. In my JSON array I have a list of places and from it I have to plot these places in my google maps in android. 
Here I am able to fetch each place, but I am only able to plot the last place in my JSON array.
I need to plot all the JSON array places in my google map.

Code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

public GoogleMap mMap;
public String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public ProgressDialog pDialog;
public String cityName;
public static String url = "http://lawgo.in/lawgo/city?format=json";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    new GetAddress().execute();
}

public void onMapSearch(View view) {

    EditText locationSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SearchLocation);
    String location = locationSearch.getText().toString();
    List<Address> addressList = null;

    if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try {
            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Address address = addressList.get(0);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(address.getFeatureName()));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 13));
    }
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
    mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Press the top right button for your location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public class GetAddress extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MapsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    public String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        //call the function where Json string is retrieved
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // getting JSON ARRAY node
                JSONArray city = jsonObj.getJSONArray("city");   // call JSON

                for (int i = 0; i < city.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = city.getJSONObject(i);

                    cityName = c.getString("cityname");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return cityName;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result){

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog

        if(pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();

        List<Address> addressList = null;

        if (result != null || !result.equals("")) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this);
            try {
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(result, 1);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Address address = addressList.get(0);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(address.getFeatureName()));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,13));
        }
    }
}}
```

Please Help! Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `onPostExecute`, You're not iterating the `addressList`. Try below code

```
for (int i = 0; i < addressList.size(); i++) {
        Address address = addressList.get(i);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(address.getFeatureName()));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,13));
}
```

**UPDATE**: To return all of the city names from doInBackground you can use an ArrayList of String type and return it from doInBackground.

Here I'm just posting the relevant codes. See if it fixes your issue.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

public GoogleMap mMap;
public String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public ProgressDialog pDialog;
public static String url = "http://lawgo.in/lawgo/city?format=json";
public ArrayList<String> cityName;


public class GetAddress extends AsyncTask<Void, String, ArrayList<String>> {

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MapsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    public String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        //call the function where Json string is retrieved
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // getting JSON ARRAY node
                JSONArray city = jsonObj.getJSONArray("city");   // call JSON

                for (int i = 0; i < city.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = city.getJSONObject(i);

                    cityName.add(c.getString("cityname"));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return cityName;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result){

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog

        if(pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();

        List<Address> addressList = null;

        if (result != null || result.size() > 0) {
          for (String cityTitle : result) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this);
            try {
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(cityTitle, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }

          for (int i = 0; i < addressList.size(); i++) {
                  Address address = addressList.get(i);
                  LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(address.getFeatureName()));
                  mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,13));
          }
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Still the same issue....the problem is in doInBackground where I am returning the string....Please help me with that.

Comment: You're only returning a single String value which is  cityName` from doInBackground hence, you're getting only the last city name in onPostExecute. You've to return the whole String array to get all the city names.

Comment: Yeah got it, could you please tell me how to do that and how to send that array to postExecute, as this is my first time using AsyncTask.

Comment: Check out updated answer. I didn't run the code but I hope you'll comprehend the basic idea just by going over it.

Comment: I solved the issue, I created an ArrayList<String>...Thank You for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the `addressList` to get all the places in map.

```
for (Address address: addressList
             ) {
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(address.getFeatureName()));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,13));
        }
```

UPDATE:

```
 private List<String> cityNameList= new ArrayList<>();  //global variable
//change the parameter of AsyncTask to change the return type of doInBackground and parameter of postExecute
    public class GetAddress extends AsyncTask<Void, String, List<String>> {

 @Override
        public List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {

            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            //call the function where Json string is retrieved
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // getting JSON ARRAY node
                    JSONArray city = jsonObj.getJSONArray("city");   // call JSON

                    for (int i = 0; i < city.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = city.getJSONObject(i);

                        cityName = c.getString("cityname");
                        cityNameList.add(cityName);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return cityNameList;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(List<String> resultList){

            super.onPostExecute(resultList);
    ....
    }
```

Comment: Still the same issue....the problem is in doInBackground where I am returning the string....Please help me with that.